# Simple Web UI to start and stop EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to create a simple Web UI that can be used to list the active EC2 instance and give my developer an easy way to start and stop the EC2 server without having log into the AWS console.

I was wondering if anyone has seen something like this before?

Comment: Why do you want to create this ui as you can perform the same using aws console?

Comment: When you're a developer yes, thats a great solution. But when you are delegating the task to someone that has to be taught everything step by step. Saying login and click this button makes much more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Use IAM to create a user, assign a policy that only allows describe, start and stop actions on the EC2 resource you want. AWS console is then your simple GUI.

Comment: Yep. Can't be any easier than that.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly create a web page like this. The easiest would be to call the commands via the [JavaScript API](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/sdk-for-javascript/), but you'd have to find a way to provide credentials.

Another option is to give them [Elastic Wolf](http://www.elasticwolf.com/), which is a desktop application. Give them a set of credentials that has the required permissions and they can view/start/stop instances via a graphical UI.

Or, just let them use the AWS Console, with scoped-down permissions to only view instances, and then start/stop.

Finally, you could just give them the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) and a simple script to turn on/off desired instances, eg:

```
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-123471b4 --region us-east-1

aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids i-123471b4 --region us-east-1
```